# Matplotlib: contour plot with data interpolation

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, contour

I use `scipy.interpolate.griddata` to interpolate my data for contour plot. The data have different scale on x and y axes:

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

xx = [0.0493, 0.0458, 0.0425, 0.0394, 0.0365, 0.0337, 0.0311, 0.0286, 0.0262, 0.024, 0.0219, 0.0198, 0.0179, 0.016, 0.0143, 0.0126, 0.0109, 0.0094, 0.0079, 0.0064, 0.005, 0.0037, 0.0024, 0.0012, 0.0, 0.0663, 0.0637, 0.0613, 0.059, 0.0567, 0.0546, 0.0525, 0.0506, 0.0487, 0.0469, 0.0451, 0.0434, 0.0418, 0.0402, 0.0387, 0.0373, 0.0359, 0.0345, 0.0332, 0.0319, 0.0307, 0.0295, 0.0283, 0.0272, 0.0261, 0.0792, 0.0774, 0.0756, 0.0739, 0.0722, 0.0706, 0.0691, 0.0676, 0.0661, 0.0647, 0.0633, 0.062, 0.0607, 0.0594, 0.0582, 0.057, 0.0559, 0.0547, 0.0536, 0.0526, 0.0515, 0.0505, 0.0495, 0.0486, 0.0477, 0.0919, 0.0905, 0.0891, 0.0878, 0.0865, 0.0852, 0.084, 0.0828, 0.0816, 0.0805, 0.0794, 0.0783, 0.0772, 0.0762, 0.0752, 0.0742, 0.0732, 0.0723, 0.0714, 0.0705, 0.0696, 0.0688, 0.0679, 0.0671, 0.0663, 0.1044, 0.1033, 0.1022, 0.1011, 0.1, 0.099, 0.098, 0.097, 0.096, 0.0951, 0.0942, 0.0933, 0.0924, 0.0915, 0.0907, 0.0898, 0.089, 0.0882, 0.0874, 0.0867, 0.0859, 0.0852, 0.0845, 0.0837, 0.083, 0.1168, 0.1159, 0.1149, 0.114, 0.1132, 0.1123, 0.1114, 0.1106, 0.1098, 0.109, 0.1082, 0.1074, 0.1066, 0.1059, 0.1052, 0.1045, 0.1037, 0.1031, 0.1024, 0.1017, 0.1011, 0.1004, 0.0998, 0.0992, 0.0985, 0.1291, 0.1283, 0.1275, 0.1267, 0.126, 0.1252, 0.1245, 0.1238, 0.123, 0.1223, 0.1217, 0.121, 0.1203, 0.1197, 0.119, 0.1184, 0.1178, 0.1172, 0.1166, 0.116, 0.1154, 0.1148, 0.1143, 0.1137, 0.1132]
yy = [0.6137, 0.8211, 1.0277, 1.2338, 1.4393, 1.6444, 1.8489, 2.053, 2.2567, 2.4601, 2.6631, 2.8658, 3.0682, 3.2703, 3.4722, 3.6738, 3.8752, 4.0763, 4.2773, 4.4781, 4.6787, 4.8791, 5.0794, 5.2795, 5.4795, 0.3217, 0.5059, 0.694, 0.8859, 1.0812, 1.2799, 1.4816, 1.6861, 1.8934, 2.1033, 2.3155, 2.5301, 2.7467, 2.9655, 3.1861, 3.4086, 3.6328, 3.8586, 4.0861, 4.315, 4.5453, 4.777, 5.01, 5.2442, 5.4795, 0.2447, 0.4154, 0.5919, 0.7737, 0.9606, 1.1524, 1.3488, 1.5496, 1.7547, 1.9638, 2.1767, 2.3932, 2.6133, 2.8367, 3.0633, 3.293, 3.5257, 3.7611, 3.9993, 4.2401, 4.4833, 4.729, 4.977, 5.2272, 5.4795, 0.1814, 0.3467, 0.5184, 0.696, 0.8795, 1.0685, 1.2629, 1.4624, 1.6668, 1.876, 2.0897, 2.3079, 2.5302, 2.7567, 2.987, 3.2212, 3.4591, 3.7004, 3.9452, 4.1933, 4.4446, 4.6989, 4.9563, 5.2165, 5.4795, 0.1202, 0.2837, 0.4538, 0.6303, 0.8128, 1.0012, 1.1953, 1.3949, 1.5998, 1.8099, 2.0249, 2.2448, 2.4693, 2.6983, 2.9318, 3.1694, 3.4112, 3.657, 3.9066, 4.16, 4.417, 4.6776, 4.9416, 5.2089, 5.4795, 0.0598, 0.2232, 0.3932, 0.5697, 0.7525, 0.9413, 1.136, 1.3365, 1.5425, 1.754, 1.9706, 2.1924, 2.4191, 2.6506, 2.8867, 3.1275, 3.3726, 3.6221, 3.8757, 4.1334, 4.3951, 4.6606, 4.93, 5.203, 5.4795, 0.0, 0.1638, 0.3344, 0.5115, 0.695, 0.8848, 1.0806, 1.2823, 1.4897, 1.7028, 1.9212, 2.145, 2.3739, 2.6078, 2.8466, 3.0903, 3.3385, 3.5914, 3.8486, 4.1102, 4.376, 4.646, 4.9199, 5.1978, 5.4795]
vv = [0.4829, 0.5196, 0.5541, 0.5866, 0.6173, 0.6463, 0.6738, 0.6998, 0.7246, 0.7481, 0.7706, 0.7919, 0.8123, 0.8318, 0.8504, 0.8683, 0.8854, 0.9017, 0.9175, 0.9326, 0.9471, 0.9611, 0.9745, 0.9875, 1.0, 0.4229, 0.4512, 0.4782, 0.5041, 0.5288, 0.5525, 0.5752, 0.597, 0.618, 0.6381, 0.6575, 0.6761, 0.6941, 0.7114, 0.7282, 0.7443, 0.7599, 0.775, 0.7895, 0.8036, 0.8173, 0.8305, 0.8433, 0.8557, 0.8678, 0.4044, 0.4259, 0.4467, 0.4668, 0.4862, 0.505, 0.5231, 0.5407, 0.5578, 0.5743, 0.5903, 0.6059, 0.621, 0.6356, 0.6498, 0.6637, 0.6771, 0.6902, 0.703, 0.7154, 0.7274, 0.7392, 0.7507, 0.7618, 0.7727, 0.3883, 0.4056, 0.4225, 0.4388, 0.4548, 0.4703, 0.4854, 0.5001, 0.5144, 0.5283, 0.5419, 0.5552, 0.5681, 0.5808, 0.5931, 0.6051, 0.6169, 0.6284, 0.6396, 0.6506, 0.6613, 0.6718, 0.6821, 0.6921, 0.7019, 0.3725, 0.3871, 0.4014, 0.4153, 0.4289, 0.4422, 0.4551, 0.4678, 0.4802, 0.4924, 0.5042, 0.5159, 0.5272, 0.5384, 0.5493, 0.56, 0.5704, 0.5807, 0.5907, 0.6006, 0.6102, 0.6197, 0.629, 0.6381, 0.6471, 0.3569, 0.3697, 0.3821, 0.3943, 0.4063, 0.418, 0.4295, 0.4407, 0.4518, 0.4626, 0.4732, 0.4836, 0.4938, 0.5038, 0.5137, 0.5233, 0.5328, 0.5421, 0.5513, 0.5603, 0.5691, 0.5778, 0.5863, 0.5947, 0.6029, 0.3415, 0.3529, 0.3641, 0.375, 0.3858, 0.3964, 0.4068, 0.417, 0.427, 0.4368, 0.4465, 0.456, 0.4654, 0.4745, 0.4836, 0.4925, 0.5012, 0.5098, 0.5182, 0.5265, 0.5347, 0.5428, 0.5507, 0.5585, 0.5662]

N=500
data_points = (xx, yy)
grid_points = (np.linspace(min(xx), max(xx), N), np.linspace(min(yy), max(yy), N))
vi = griddata(data_points, vv, 
              (grid_points[0][None, :], grid_points[1][:, None]), method='cubic')

plot(xx,yy, '.k')
contour(grid_points[0], grid_points[1], vi)
```

But I got ugly sharped contours:

[image]

However, if I scale for example the y axis, like this `yy = [v/50. for v in yy]`, I got the smoothed plot:

[image]

How to get the smoothed contours with original axes scales?

Comment: griddata calculates a "distance" to nearby points and weights by those distances.  If your x and y values are such that they are in different units, then this distances will be skewed so that, in your case, the `x` values usually have more weight than the `y`.   In order to fix this, you hit on exactly the correct solution, and rescaled your `y` to be more similar to `x`.  To get the original, just don't overwrite `yy`, and plot with that..  

Note `griddata` also has a `rescale` argument which will do this for your automatically.